# Unable to connect in China

Tags: vpn, browsers, ios

I'm from the UK, but I work as an English teacher in China. Usually I get around the Chinese firewall by using a VPN, but lately the government has been stepping up their efforts to block these, so I downloaded Red Browser for my iPhone as an alternative method of getting around the firewall and maintaining contact with the outside world. However, the only way that I've been able to connect through Red Browser is with my VPN turned on. Without it I get no connection.

Is there anything else I can do to connect in China? I read something about 'bridges', but I don't really know what that means.

Answer (score 2):

[Sebastian](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/6883/sebastian) advised you to use the meek transport. However you can also use the current version of Tor browser. This has support for a new protocol called [obfs4](https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/obfs4.git/). Just use the dropdown menu at the green onion and at network settings choose obfs4 as transport type. As far as I know obfs4 bridges work quite good inside China. The older protocol obfs3 usually works for some time (between 10 minutes and an hour) until the bridges are detected and blocked.

Comment: obfs3 still works in china. Actually for users who want to orbot (Tor for android) and did not upgrade ROM to lollipop, obfs3 is the only option for users in China. BTW: since when can gfw detect and block obfs3 bridges in 10-60 minites?

Answer (score 1):

Bridges are a way to make a connection not directly with the Tor network, but using a server that isn't part of the official network even tho it runs Tor. Unfortunately, they don't work in China. What does work as far as I know is the meek transport. You can get it by using the normal [Tor Browser](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-404-released). [Here's](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek) the documentation for how it works.